# jQuery UI Datepicker onSelect clear value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

My input field has a default `value` and I want to clear this as soon as the user clicks on a date. I tried to do this with the `onSelect` event but it didn't work, because it also clears the selected (new) date.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$("#date-input").datepicker({showAnim: 'slideDown', dateFormat: 'MMMM Do, YYYY', onSelect: function() {
        $('#date-input').val("");
    }});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `beforeShow` method:

```
 $("#date-input").datepicker({
       showAnim: 'slideDown', 
       dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
       beforeShow: function(){
           this.value='';
     }
 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvxvqxeL/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clearing date `onSelect` try `focus` event :

```
 $('#date-input').focus(function(){
    $(this).val("");
 });

 $("#date-input").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'  });
```

and also correct dateformat as shown above.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Loa5v4r2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#DateInput').datepicker({
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            onSelect: function () {
                var selectedDate = $(this).val();
                $('#DateInput').val("");
                $('#DateInput').val(selectedDate);
            }
        });
```